# Find the maximum displacement given trajectory.

Tags: physics

I'm trying to find the maximum displacement of a object given the trajectory.
The trajectory is given by the equation:
$$p(t)=-11.79t^2+25.9t+4.35$$
Looking around online, the closest article I've seen says that the maximum displacement is when $v(t)=0$, and velocity is the derivative of the trajectory (position as a function of time). what I have done is:
$$v(t)=\frac d{dt}[-11.79t^2+25.9t+4.35]$$
$$v(t)=-23.58t+25.9$$
$$0=-23.58t+25.9$$
$$t=\frac{25.9}{23.58}=1.098388465$$
Then plugging this into the original equation gives the max displacement as $$displacement=47.02239186$$

Is this even remotely correct? If not, how would one go about finding the max displacement given a trajectory? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect you mean $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

Comment: You're correct.  I should have read over it a little better before submitting. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done exactly what was expected, but when you plugged your $t$ into the displacement equation you made an error.  Just plugging in $t=1$ we have $p(1)=18.46$

Comment: You're correct.  When plugging it into the calculator I forgot the negative in front of the first term.  Thank you for your help.